# Increment a value within a jQuery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

As simple as this might seem, I have tried 10 different ways and just can't seem to increment the object value correctly.

Here is the code:

```js
function getItem() {
 
 var item = {
  TotalUsers: $("#userCount").val(),
        RequestType: $("input[name=requestType]:checked").val(),
        SessionType: $("input[name=sessionType]:checked").val(),
   };
   return item;
}

function AddListItem(resources) {
 
 var item = getItem();
 
 if (item.RequestType == "Team" && item.SessionType == "Remote Session") {
  item.TotalUsers = ++item.TotalUsers;
 }
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group row userCount">
   <label for="userCount" class="col-form-label">Total users:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="userCount" type="number" min="0" id="userCount" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid number." placeholder="Ex: 25" required/>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
```

I have a function grab the input from a list perfectly, then I have the number stored in a variable perfectly.

How do I get item.TotalUsers to increment by 1 in this code below? It outputs the number correctly to the list but it doesn't increase it by +1.

```
if (item.RequestType == "Team" && item.SessionType == "Remote Session") {
            item.TotalUsers = ++item.TotalUsers;
        }
```

Comment: Your code does that but it doesn't change the `#userCount` element value. In fact, your code effectively doesn't do anything.

Comment: In Chrome dev mode, I was able to see the item increment but it just wasn't allowing me to submit the form anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each call to `getItem()` you are getting a new `item` object, it's not clear what are you trying to do but I think you should increment the input instead :

```
if (your condition) {
  $("#userCount").val(parseInt(item.TotalUsers, 10) + 1);
}
```

Comment: In Chrome dev mode, I was able to see the item increment but it just wasn't allowing me to submit the form anymore.

I'll try this method.

Comment: All this does is add +1 to the end of my input such as "input: 12 = 121" .. I'd like to "input: 12 +1 = 13"

Sorry about the confusion

Comment: I've edited the answer, it's because you're storing it as a string, you need to parse it to int, either there or in `getItem()`